# Why are C#'s format specifiers strings?

Tags: c#, string-formatting, language-design

Why are format specifiers to base types in C# of type `string` instead of a less error-prone and more readable type, like `enum`? While I know many of the specifiers by now, I almost always have to [double-check the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types) to avoid bugs or weird edge-cases. `enum` types and values could've easily provided that information in their comments.

C#'s version 1.0 was released in [2002](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-version-history#c-version-10), and `object.ToString()` has been a feature since C# 1.1. It is an old feature and I understand that the development process and goals doesn't necessarily look the same now as then. However, I cannot understand the reason for not using a type-safe, well-defined and easy-to-document behavior by using language features such as enums or classes instead of strings.

Of course, most older langauges such as C use `string` type format specifiers, so perhaps it's just by convention? If so, why do they feel the need to follow that convention? (and besides, C use the `%` character for specifiers, so C# already made up their own conventions)

Comment: Because it allow user to define new custom specifiers on any custom type

Comment: The most likely answer here, as it usually is for these types of questions, is that it's just how the language makers decided to do it.

Comment: How would you define something like `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss','fff")` using an enum? I would love to have enums for `double` etc. though

Comment: @Fixation But even there, you can add number of decimals, padding etc ...

Comment: Enums by their inherent nature are closed to extension.  Strings seem far more pragmatic when building an API that could change in needs and use cases down the road.

Comment: It's difficult to see how you'd be able to reuse enums, etc in `string.Format` format strings (at least if you expected the type safety benefits you seem to be seeking)

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding; I'll respond to each of you in turn.

Comment: @Kalten I do not see how that's relevant for most common use-cases: You can't really expand on Int32.ToString()'s (default) behaviors. I do suppose, however, that it makes sense when using a custom formatter.

Comment: @Fixation You could do a couple of tricks with flags... But I understand what you mean, though. I thought about that some time after posting the question.

Comment: @DavidL That is true, enums are fixed by design. The more I read into the design of the formatters, the more sense it makes to use strings to allow more wide or narrow format specifiers. With that said, I still believe it to be handy to have the base types' ToString() overrides to have an enum-based overload...

Answer (score -2):

It's because they expect the format will vary a lot in different cultures, countries, systems, users (some systems allow users to choose their own prefer format). And we will end up a very big enum for all possibilities. And also, .net framework can't just maintain a huge amount of formats.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I follow. The current formatting system already has a certain amount of culture-management built in. What I'm primarily asking about is the standard numeric format strings and the standard date and time format strings.

Comment: Sure, the .net framework already support quite many cultures. But not all users use those default formats.